# Рекурсивный двоичный поиск на С++

Tags: c++, двоичный-поиск

День добрый. Реализовал рекурсивный двоичный поиск, но время от времени переполняется стек. В чем проблема?

```
int bin_search(vector<int> & arr, int left, int right, int number) {
    int mid = left / 2 + right / 2;

    if (left > right) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (left <= right) {
        if (number == arr[mid]) {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (number > arr[mid]) {
            bin_search(arr, mid + 1, right, number);
        }
        else {
            bin_search(arr, left, mid - 1, number);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое, то нашел - это следующая строка

```
int mid = left / 2 + right / 2;
```

она не всегда ищет "середину". допустим, что left и right равны 1, тогда mid будет равно 0. А это не совсем то, что ожидается. Если взять два других нечетных числа, то будет такая же ситуация или около того. Например, при 3 и 5, середина у Вас получается 3 (1 + 2)

при двух 1 эта строка скорее всего и приводит к зацикливанию.

Как избежать подобных ошибок? добавьте в список `#include <cassert>`, а в коде после данного вычисления добавьте такое

```
assert(mid >= left);
assert(right>=mid);
```

и ошибка сама всплывет.